# GA enhanced e-commerce not tracking events through tagmanager

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

We have a GA enhanced e-commerce set up on our e-commerce, and it's working fine. Now, we want to use tagmanager because we are using many other tags like mousestats, criteo, etc.

I had set up an UA tag in tagmanager with "Page View" trigger and with: "Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features", "Use data layer" and "Enable Display Advertising Features" enabled.

It was tracking user access but was not tracking "add to cart", "purchase", "product details", etc. I think it's not tracking because all those events are ajax requests, so it happens after a "page view".

Everything seems to be working fine with "preview mode", i can see all events (e.g: add to cart) there, and all scripts are following the https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce. But no e-commerce results appears at analytics.

Should i create an UA event trigger for each of those events? or are we doing something wrong? I thought that if we used datalayer it would automatically track all events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to capture any information after the pageview has loaded (either actions like add to cart, or Ajax) you will be required to send an event with the Enhanced Ecommerce data.

In the link you provided, there are sections after each of the required tags named "See the Tag Configuration for this Example". https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

If you click on this, it will provide the basic information for the required tags, e.g. add to cart events.

As for ajax (which I assume is for loading your product details) you might need to send additional events when the Enhanced Ecommerce data is available.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see those sections, It's easier than i thought. :)